# FreeRTOS error occurring in Xtensa IDE for HiFi_5

Tags: fatal-error, freertos, xaf, xtensa

I downloaded the XAF code from https://github.com/foss-xtensa/xaf-hostless/tree/master and tried to build it using Xtensa IDE (Windows Platform, HiFi_5 processor, IDE version: Version 8.0.16).

I am getting an error `fatal error: 'FreeRTOS.h' file not found`. I tried to resolve this, but unable to fix it.  Can anyone please guide on how to fix this error ?